# Difference Between StreamWriter/Reader and StringWriter/Readerll

Tags: c#

Im very confused with the exact difference between them and different usage approach of these two TextWriter/Reader derived types StringWriter/Reader and StreamReader/Reader.
I know that using them we can deal easily with character based data in stream avoiding byte fuss as working direclty using Filestream...

Comment: it would be helpful if you could clarify what the question is exactly; e.g. what do you need to do...  yes, those things can ease dealing with data significantly, if that's the question.

Comment: hm.. I think you already responded to you own question. So what is your confusion about?

Comment: The name may hint their usage.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

- **TextWriter/Reader** is an abstract class. It provides an abstraction for writing/reading character based data to/from a data source.
- **StreamWriter/Reader** is a concrete implementation that uses a writeable/readable [Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx) as data source. Since a Stream is abstraction for writing/reading byte based data, an [Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx) instance is required for the translation between characters and bytes.
- **StringWriter/Reader** is a concrete implementation that uses a [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx)/[string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) as data source.

Comment: I got it... StreamWriter/Reader is basically Writing/Reading characters to/from underlying stream...since stream operates on bytes, with the help of encoding functionality implemented by this type automatically converts characters into bytes(unlike FileStream) so it's kind of ease of usage...Whereas StringReader/Writer performs on string data rather than stream...

Answer (score 16):

The `Stream*` classes read from a `Stream`.
The `String*` classes read from a `String` (and write to a `StringBuilder`).

You can write a method that takes a `TextReader`, and call it with a `StreamReader` or a `StringReader` for it to read from a stream or a string.

Answer (score 2):

here you have the difference

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/9e86374b-bdab-4d33-b0de-e72f8f7e913e